# WordPress 4.7 REST API Example Request does not work

Tags: wordpress, rest, curl

I'm using successfully the WordPress 4.7 REST API in this way:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic mykey" -X POST --data-urlencode "title=Something" www.myhost.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/770
```

The example in the new [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/) suggests:

```
curl -X POST http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json -d '{"title":"My New Title"}'
```

which obvious is a wrong endpoint. Adapting to

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic mykey" -X POST www.myhost.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/770 --data-urlencode '{"title":"My New Title"}'
```

does not change the title but simply returns the post as JSON

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came over my own question, which I did resolve a long time ago. Just if someone struggles with this too.

First of course, posting data with curl requires the `-d` option an **not** the `--data-urlencode`. Second, the REST endpoint needs to know the type of data. Here JSON. So setting the correct Content Type is essential.

This is a complete example:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic mykey>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"title":"Something"}' www.myhost.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/770
```